# Write a text based on the numbers of another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have this data with a lot of different PINs. Each PIN corresponds with a product, so `PIN 1205463MB` means a product. I want to write the PIN in a cell and automatic write the product name in the next column.

I tried the `VLOOKUP` function and didn't work , any suggestions?
I already tried this formula I found in a Stack Overflow post, but didn't work either.

```
=INDEX($B$4:$K$9;MATCH($A$17;$A$5:$A$9;0);COLUMN(A4))
```

Also in a near future another PIN will be added and then the answer to my problem need to be an easy one to adapt.

[image]

Comment: Please share a test sheet or a usable image. Also, use ONLY relevant tags.

Comment: sorry, is a work sheet and i can't share with people outside of the company

Comment: Just create a new test sheet with dummy info.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14U1eCDo3qWVNUFFyqhKS_kXOr1vtOtVfLwUy8hcaJEc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to make it public.

Comment: And now it does not even exist. :(

Comment: I don't have the option to make public, but below is a example.                                               PIN                  Product                                                                                                           1225MB          Computer                                                                                                         1555CV           HeadSet                                                                                                           5548AM          Card

Comment: sorry for make so hard man

Comment: *"I don't have the option to make public"*. As mentioned, share a usable image. Have a look at other questions on the site on how to do that. *"PIN Product 1225MB Computer 1555CV HeadSet 5548AM Card"* This is just a line. More data is needed. Use [this link](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to form your data to usable ones.

Comment: i add a image to the post, hope you can see the image.

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, your Question has to be self-contained. Meaning all the information needs to be within this Question itself. A link is not sufficient. This means that even if you could make your sheet public, it would not suffice. This is due to the fact that links may not be working later on. cc @marikamitsos

Comment: @Scratte I agree with you. But. As you can see while I was trying to get to what you ask for, another user already answered the question. Check the timelines

Comment: @marikamitsos Yes, I know. I only put you on cc as I wasn't sure you knew about it from the comments I saw:) It's tricky to get post in good order before it's answered. Unfortunately it's not very useful for anyone at its current state, so it should be closed.

Comment: @Scratte Hard to find new users posting self-contained questions. Even harder to make them understand it. Even worst, when someone answers such a question the OP loses all interest on improving it and just flees the grounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `VLOOKUP` as it is exactly what you are asking to do:

In this image you can see on the left I have the table with the pins and its product names.

[image]

Then on the right, I put another column where I will manually insert the PIN. The column next to it has a dynamic formula (which means that it will fill in the rows below if necessary) that will look for the value you put on the left.

```
=ArrayFormula( if( len(D2:D), VLOOKUP($D2:D, A2:B16, 2, false),))
                                      ^^^^^  ******  ^  *****
arguments:                             ||     ||     |    ||
1. column with manually inserted pin----|     ||     |    ||
2. whole table you are looking for the value---|     |    ||
3. number of column you want to retrieve (prod name)-|    ||
4. flag to say the table is not sorted---------------------|
```

This means, every PIN that you will have on the left will have the product name automatically setup on the column with the formula. The dynamic formula as you can see fills the whole column, as I put a random pin on the cell `D6` and it filled the product name as well.